# Hypothetical sentence construction

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

- If you asked, I would follow.
- If you ask, I will follow.

The first one is hypothetical, and suggests that something is likely to happen if the condition is met.

Truly to say, it seems to me that the two examples stated above have same meanings. But I'm in doubt.

Please say what actually is.

Comment: The second is more likely to happen, from the standpoint of the speaker. In the first sentence, the speaker doubts the likelihood of "asking".

Comment: For all practical purposes there is little difference in meaning between the two sentences. It is true that the first one talks about a hypothetical situation, but on the other hand, one cannot predict the future. So they mean about the same. Another example: *If it rained tommorow I would go* and *If it rains tomorrow I will go*.

Answer (score 2):

These constructions are what is known to be **conditionals**.
When you want to predict the *result* of a future action, you invoke the **first conditional**. (Your second sentence.)

Note that the modals *may, might* and *could* can be used instead of *will* in the result clause, so your sentence can also be written as *If you ask, I may/might/could follow.*
On a decreasing percentage, the predictions are shown as follows:

> *will* → *will probably* → *could, may, might*
>   100%          90%                       70%                       
>   → *may/might not* → *probably won't* → *won't*
>                 40%                     10%               0%

The **second conditional** (first sentence) is used to talk about situations that are *unlikely* or *unreal*. It can refer to the *present* or the *future*, so the sentence *If you asked, I'd follow*, refers to an unreal situation in the present.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence:

> If + the present simple tense, the future simple tense

is the first conditional. We use it to talk about a **likely or probable** situation **in the future**, i.e. *If I get this job, I'll have a party to celebrate it*. I may get the job, I may not, I don't know,  but it's possible- I applied and I have a chance to get it.

The first sentence:

> If + the past simple tense, would + a verb

is the second conditional. We use it to talk about a **unlikely or unreal** situation **in the future** or *alternative or unreal* situation **in the present**, i.e. *If I won the lottery, I'd buy a mansion*. The odds are that I won't win (unlikely future). Or *If I were working now, I'd be tired*. I'm not working now - I'm relaxed (unreal or alternative present).